# Catch specific exceptions with try...except

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some code to rename a whole bunch of files and move them to a new directory using `os.rename()`.  Its fairly simple, nothing flashy.  It worked until I had some overlap in batches and there were duplicate files, this raised a `WindowsError`.  Since the code worked in all otherways, I did

```
try:
    os.rename(...)
except WindowsError:
    print "Duplicate file {}".format(fileName)
```

This worked fine, except that it implies that all `WindowsError`s are from duplicate files.  The result was that when another aspect of my script broke, it failed essentially silently.

How can I employ `try...except` to catch only specific exceptions? If its not possible, what workarounds exist?

Comment: you could try `catch WindowsError as e:` and look at `str(e)`, and `dir(e)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I thought about that, but aren't the strings associated with exceptions system dependent?

Comment: The full text of the error message isn't guaranteed to be the same on all systems, so if I'm searching that text for some description of the error, how will I know what to search for?

Comment: im guessing all versions of windows would result in a simillar enough message you could look for a keyword or two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.WindowsError):

"The [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno) value maps the **`winerror`** value to corresponding `errno.h` values."

Because of this, you should be able to distinguish between different Windows errors by using `errno`.

Example:

```
try:
    fp = open("nother")
except IOError as e:
    print e.errno
    print e
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a context manager to suppress `OSError` based on `errno` value.  Here's that context manager, just rewritten a little bit to catch `WinError` instead.

Your example code prints a message when the error occurs, but this won't print anything; it silently suppresses the exception.

I haven't tested this because I don't have Windows handy, but I tested the original and this is a trivial edit.  Let me know if you have any trouble with this.

The `.__exit__()` method function gets information about any received exceptions, and if it returns `True` the exception is suppressed; if it returns `False` the exception is raised as normal.  Thus this only suppresses the exception if the type matches (it was a `WinError` exception) and the `.errno` attribute matches the saved `self.errno` value.

```
class suppress_winerror(object):
    def __init__(self, errno):
        self.errno = errno

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, e_type, e_val, e_tb):
        if e_type is not WinError:
            return False
        if e_val.errno != self.errno:
            return False
        return True
```

Example of how to use this.  I'm assuming that the windows error code is being mapped onto `errno.EEXIST`, the `errno` code for "file already exists".  Obviously if I got this wrong, you should put the correct error code instead.

```
import errno

with suppress_winerror(errno.EEXIST):
    os.rename(old_fname, new_fname)
```